# How to set max,count,active and inactive configuration in phusion passanger

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to set below configuration in phusion passenger.

```
max      = 6
count    = 2
active   = 2
inactive = 0
Waiting on global queue = 0
```

Can you please tell me where to set this.

Comment: Ref:- http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerUseGlobalQueue